# Mass spectrum of N,N-dimethylaminoethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

I have been struggling with understanding how fragmentation works in mass spectrometry. An exercise my teacher gave me asked me to prove that a mass spectrum belongs to N,N-dimethylaminoethane, CH<sub>3</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>N(CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>. The mass spectrum is shown below:

[image]

I worked out that the peak at m/e = 58 is due to the loss of CH<sub>3</sub> from the molecular ion (resulting in a fragment with an ethyl and methyl group bonded to an N<sup>+</sup>), but I can't figure out what the fragments are at the m/e = 44, 42 and 30 peaks. I've tried several ways to determine it, such as the cleavage of two bonds and rearrangement, but I still can't find it. How do you find out the fragments for those m/e peaks?

Also, in general, is there a clear-cut way to determine fragments at each m/e peak?

Comment: A candidate for m/z = 44 is $\ce{CH3N=CH2^+}$ or $\ce{CH3CH=NH2^+}$ . For m/z = 42, $\ce{CH2=N=CH2^+}$. For m/z = 30, $\ce{CH2=NH2^+}$

Comment: If you think you will have a lot of mass spec questions in the future, you may want to support [this proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126894/mass-spectrometry?referrer=YTEyYzgzY2Y0ZTU0MDkwNzA1MWI3NzAzZjc5ZDI0NTA3Y2UyMjIxYTFjY2ViNmRjZDRhOTRlMzQxMGYwNWUyYbM20jLlza-N1haS_st25xbu5y0X1WWo_7I_beGI737z0) for a whole site dedicated to mass spec.

Comment: "cleavage of two bonds and rearrangement"? There's hardly anything to rearrange here. Just cut some bonds... This is a quite simple example, and you complicate even the name of the compound,

Comment: A candidate for m/z = 44 is $\ce{N(CH3)2^+}$

Comment: @Mithoron Sorry for the confusion! The name of the molecule was given to me in the question––I do know that N,N-dimethylethanamine would be a better name to represent the molecule. I'm relatively new to mass spectrometry, so I'm not really familiar with 'simple' examples! Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user55119 Thanks for the answer! But wouldn't your suggestion for m/z = 44 have the m/z of 43 instead (the first candidate)?

Comment: I forgot an "H". The first m/z = 44 cation should be $\ce{CH3NH=CH2^+}$.